# How to get CQL_FILTER parameters from vector polygon

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, cql-filter

map projection is EPSG:900913, displayprojection for map EPSG:4326. 
vector layer is polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon Layer"); with draw polygoon option

with following code I get CQL_FILTER

```
var myLatLonSquare = polygonLayer.features[0].geometry.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));

var testArray = "WITHIN(GEOM, ";

testArray = testArray + myLatLonSquare;

testArray = testArray.replace("MULTIPOLYGON(", "POLYGON");

antennaLayer.mergeNewParams({
    "CQL_FILTER": testArray
});
```

as it's shown on the images(the site does not let me to upload images yet) it gets different location coordinates. How to solve it?

UPDATED:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didnt understand why did you tranform your point to 4326 to 4326? Do you think this is not the problem for wrong location?

and openlayers cql [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/cql-format.html) is so good to understand it. firstly you are defining CQL parser then you can get your filter with `format.read(cql.value)`. The last thing is that adding your features to your map... You can also add your filter in Openlayers rule and using it your vector layer as style `new OpenLayers.Style(null, {rules: [rule]})`

**UPDATE**:

Adding projection to vector layer.

```
    var wgs84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line Vectors", {
        style: {
            strokeColor: "blue",
            strokeWidth: 3,
            cursor: "pointer"
        },
        eventListeners: {
            "featuresadded": dataLoaded
        },
        projection: wgs84
    }));
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I was playing with numbers 4326, 900913, 32638, but no sense.. I know this link but problem is the vector layer has wrong projection and I cannot understand how to change it...
can I assign to vector layer projection while adding it to map?

Comment: absolutely, you can add projection to vectorlayer when adding it to map. i have updated my answer..